# Can two customers use same source on Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a rails application in which stripe is implemented. However, I am getting an error in Stripe that says

> for security reasons you cannot directly charge a source that is already attached to a customer.....

What I guessed from the error is that a card/source was already attached to a customer and some other customer is trying to pay with that card. Is it the case? Or is there something else?

And how to handle such scenarios on the developer end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, once a source is attached to customer A then you can't use it with customer B.

To avoid that error, make sure that each customer has their own Source and verify that the Source and Customers match when trying to create a charge.